# How to create a SDK on Android?

Tags: android, sdk

I developed an Android app with Android Studio and I want now to create a SDK to enable other developer to use the technology I created. This SDK should use an activity and a couple of background service.

I've looked around on internet and on SO, but I did not manage to find the basic information I need :

- How to set Android Studio to build a SDK , not an APK;
- Is there any security to implement so that my code is not readable by others?

I created an app but I have no basic knowledge on building SDK, so any information or link where I can learn would be appreciated.

Comment: A sdk is almost the same as a library collection with documentations.

Comment: Not sure what a module is. I'm not really an experienced Android developer. And I never created a library either, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me what you require is a .aar file. Just like you give out Java sdk's as a jar, you can package your Android code as a .aar file. This can be imported in any other Android project and your exposed API's / screens can be used directly.
To create an aar select your module in Android studio project structure- then on the right pane select gradle and then select generate .aar file. This will be generated in your build/outputs folder.
Now this can be added in any project and compiled by putting a dependency in the gradle. You can Google "creating an aar" for more information.